# Simple and secure Python console menu without conditionals or match case statements

Tags: python, console

I'm writing a basic tutorial for a simple console menu for Python. I think it is secure, since the `input()` is controlled by a `dispatch`. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```py
"""
Nice Menu for Python
"""
import time  # used only for testing purposes


def m_help():
    """
- - - - - - - - -
Micro Menu Help
- help line 1
- Help line 1
- - - - - - - - -"""
    print(m_help.__doc__)
    m_message('...')


def m_message(message):
    """Message."""
    print(f'|===> {message} <===|')
    time.sleep(0.70)  # slow down to see the message


def m_not_found():
    """not found."""
    m_message('Choice NOT found, please try again.')


def m_view():
    """View."""
    m_message('`m_view` function was called.')


def m_delete():
    """Delete."""
    m_message('`m_delete` function was called.')


def m_quit():
    """Quit program."""
    m_message('`m_quit` function was called.')
    quit()


def menu_text():
    """
Welcome to Micro Menu
1] View (v)
2] Delete
3] Help
4] Quit (q)
    """
    print(menu_text.__doc__)


def menu(index):
    """ Will return a function based on the index."""

    dispatcher = {
        '1': m_view,
        '2': m_delete,
        '3': m_help,
        '4': m_quit,
        'v': m_view,   # alternative key to '1'
        'q': m_quit  # alternative key to '3'
        # ...
    }
    return dispatcher.get(index, m_not_found)


def main():
    """Main function."""
    while True:
        menu_text()
        choice = input('>> Make your choice: ')
        menu(choice)()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Secure? Against what? And why specifically are you avoiding conditionals? Is that an external challenge or something you've decided to design for on your own?

Comment: Thanks, not sure about security, just didn't want to use `eval()`.

I've built several simple menus with conditionals and `match()`, but I thought this was a more readable and simpler approach. 
Conditional seem messy:
https://computinglearner.com/how-to-create-a-menu-for-a-python-console-application/

The menu was just something I wanted to build to practice with Python, since I've been away from Python for many years. I'm writing a complete tutorial on TinyDB, and wanted a simple menu to demonstrate all the database functions.

Comment: All quite sensible; thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `print(__doc__)` pattern is an interesting one but not one that I recommend. Docstrings are meant to document the function itself, and your `m_help` docstring is not that: instead, presumably, it documents the program. Those are not the same thing.

`m_function` is a little odd as a naming convention. Either spell it out - `menu_function` - or drop the prefix entirely and make an enclosing module called `menu`.

Since you're just doing simple appends,

```
print(f'|===> {message} <===|')
```

can be expressed as

```
print('|===>', message, '<===|')
```

Do not `sleep`. "Slowing down to see the message" should not be a concern for this application since you have so little content. If your content grows, sleeping is still not the solution; you would instead want to paginate.

Your code is not DRY (don't-repeat-yourself) enough. You write the "index" characters in multiple places. There are many ways to centralise this; I show one below.

Try your best to avoid `quit()`. One simple way is to return a flag from your dispatched functions indicating whether the menu loop needs to `break`.

`"""View."""`, as a comment, is less helpful than having no comment at all. Similar for most of your other comments.

### Suggested

```
"""
Nice Menu for Python
"""
from typing import Any, Callable, NamedTuple, Iterable, Iterator


def menu_help() -> None:
    print("""
- - - - - - - - -
Micro Menu Help
- help line 1
- help line 2
- - - - - - - - -""")
    menu_message('...')


def menu_message(message: str) -> None:
    print('|===>', message, '<===|')


def menu_not_found() -> None:
    menu_message('Choice not found; please try again.')


def menu_view() -> None:
    pass


def menu_delete() -> None:
    pass


def menu_quit() -> bool:
    return True


class MenuItem(NamedTuple):
    index: tuple[str, ...]
    name: str
    callback: Callable[[], Any]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        desc = f'{self.index[0]}] {self.name}'
        if len(self.index) > 1:
            others = ', '.join(self.index[1:])
            desc += f' ({others})'
        return desc


def menu_fragments(items: Iterable[MenuItem]) -> Iterator[str]:
    yield 'Welcome to Micro Menu'
    for item in items:
        yield str(item)


def menu_text(items: Iterable[MenuItem]) -> None:
    print('\n'.join(menu_fragments(items)))


def menu(dispatcher: dict[str, MenuItem], index: str) -> Callable[[], Any]:
    """ Will return a function based on the index."""

    item = dispatcher.get(index)
    if item is None:
        return menu_not_found

    # Delete this once you're done debugging the program
    menu_message(f'`{item.name}` function was called.')
    return item.callback


def main() -> None:
    items = (
        MenuItem(('1', 'v'), 'View', menu_view),
        MenuItem(('2',), 'Delete', menu_delete),
        MenuItem(('3',), 'Help', menu_help),
        MenuItem(('4', 'q'), 'Quit', menu_quit),
    )

    dispatcher = {
        index: item
        for item in items
        for index in item.index
    }

    while True:
        menu_text(items)
        choice = input('>> Make your choice: ').strip().lower()
        if menu(dispatcher, choice)():
            break
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I'm studying your work carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This question is generic, under-specified**. The menu offers two reasonably
clear choices (help and quit) and two that raise questions (view and delete).
View and delete what exactly? Typically operations like that involve additional
arguments: "view database record 123", "delete items older that 10 days", and
so forth. Maybe view and delete refer to "everything", in which case no
arguments are required. But unless we know the nature of the required
arguments, the most natural way to arrange the relationships and data-flow
between `main()` and the menu functions is not entirely clear.

**Don't cause side effects in the menu functions**. In spite of that ambiguity,
one general piece advice -- at least in more serious projects where you intend
to subject the code to a battery of automated tests -- is to spend the extra
design time to create a system where the functions doing the real work (the
menu functions in our case) don't cause side effects like printing or exiting.
Instead, arrange things so that those functions take arguments (data) and
return information (more data). Functions like that can be directly tested
without hassle. In the illustration below, that data is wrapped in a `Result`
object, which can be extended or modified as needed.

**Questionable functions: `menu_text()` and `menu()`**. The former is a
constant pretending to be a function. Just define the constant and be done with
it. The latter is a `dict.get()` call pretending to be a function. It's also a
function so intimately tied to its caller that it doesn't have much independent
utility. I would suggest moving the dispatching data (the dict) into `main()`
and then writing a function that does something independently useful: take a
prompt and a valid set of choices (the dict keys in this case) and return a
validated user reply. In the case at hand, I also arranged the function to
return additional arguments in the reply in anticipation that some of the
operations (like view and delete) will require additional parameters.

**DRY up the code**. In scripts like this, you have various tasks that need to
be dispatched. Those tasks have names, one or more ways for the user to choose
them (eg, a number or first letter from the name), an associated function to
perform the task, and maybe some task-specific help text. Your current
`menu_text()` and `m_help()` implementations work against DRYing up the code.
To illustrate a different way of approaching the script, I might start with
some constants and a dataclass similar in spirit to the one suggested in another
review:

```
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable

WELCOME = '\nWelcome to Micro Menu\n'
MENU_TASK_FMT = '{}] {} ({})'
REPORTING_FMT = '`menu_{}` function was called with {}.'
PROMPT = '>> Make your choice: '
INVALID_CHOICE = 'Invalid choice.'

TASK_HELP = dict(
    View = 'View...',
    Delete = 'Delete...',
    Help = 'Help...',
    Quit = 'Quit...',
)

@dataclass(frozen = True)
class MenuTask:
    name: str
    num: int
    func: Callable
    help_text: str

    @property
    def letter(self):
        return self.name[0].lower()
```

Then the task functions might look like this. Currently, they don't do anything
interesting other than report how they were called, except
perhaps in the case of the quit-task.

```
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Result:
    out: str = None
    err: str = None
    exit_code: int = None

def menu_view(args):
    msg = REPORTING_FMT.format('view', args)
    return Result(out = msg)

def menu_delete(args):
    msg = REPORTING_FMT.format('delete', args)
    return Result(out = msg)

def menu_help(args):
    help_text = '\n'.join(t.help_text for t in TASKS)
    msg = REPORTING_FMT.format('help', args) + '\n' + help_text
    return Result(out = msg)

def menu_quit(args):
    msg = REPORTING_FMT.format('quit', args)
    return Result(out = msg, exit_code = 0)
```

You can also define constant holding those tasks. The current definition relies on
a naming convention and `globals()`. Adjust as desired if you prefer a more
explicit or direct approach.

```
TASKS = tuple(
    MenuTask(
        name,
        i + 1,
        globals()['menu_' + name.lower()],
        help_text,
    )
    for i, (name, help_text) in enumerate(TASK_HELP.items())
)
```

Finally, we have the portion of the program that cannot easily avoid side
effects: `main()` and its primary helper functions.

```
def main():
    # Assemble the menu text.
    menu_text = WELCOME + '\n'.join(
        MENU_TASK_FMT.format(t.num, t.name, t.letter)
        for t in TASKS
    )

    # Set up dispatching data.
    dispatch = {
        choice : t
        for t in TASKS
        for choice in (str(t.num), t.letter)
    }
    choices = tuple(dispatch)

    # Perform tasks requested by user.
    while True:
        print(menu_text)
        choice, args = get_reply(PROMPT, choices)
        task = dispatch[choice]
        res = task.func(args)
        act_on_result(res)

def get_reply(prompt, choices):
    print(prompt + ': ')
    while True:
        if xs := input().split():
            c, *args = xs
            if c in choices:
                return (c, args)
        print(INVALID_CHOICE)

def act_on_result(res):
    # Write messages.
    if res.out is not None:
        print(res.out)
    if res.err is not None:
        print(res.err, file = sys.stderr)

    # Maybe exit.
    if res.exit_code is not None:
        sys.exit(res.exit_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What do you do if you also want to be able to subject `main()` and its
immediate helpers to hassle-free automated testing? One approach is to stick
them in a simple class that takes optional parameters for their own `stdout`,
`stderr`, and `stdin` attributes. During automated testing you initialize the
class with `io.StringIO` objects which can be inspected by the test code. In
real usage, those attributes default the standard streams supplied by `sys`. The
class never uses `print()` or `input()`; instead it writes to its own `stdout`
and `stderr` and reads from its own `stdin`. In addition, the class never calls
`sys.exit()`. Instead, if `main()` gets a `Result` having an exit code it just
breaks from the loop and the function ends in a peaceful fashion. At a certain
point, even the most determined must embrace the conditional.

Comment: I really appreciate the help and for the time you put in.  I'm studying your work carefully. Thanks!